# Angular 5 app doesn't register service worker

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker

I've an app that I already had built and SW were working fine. I continue to develop without paying attention to SW ...
And now, there is no more SW getting download while charging the app (as if the app was not registring the SW).

**I'm pretty desesperate as I have no idea on how to debug/found clue on that issue**.
How can I track the SW registring process ?

**More context:**

- I have:

  - `"serviceWorker": true` in .angular-cli.json
  - `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })` in my app.module.ts
  - build my app in prod mod and served it with http-server (both ngsw.json and ngsw-worker.js are accessible)
  - clean cache in dev mode (regular cache and application/clear storage)
- I tried to:

  - change app.module imports order (i tried `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })` first, second after BrowserModule and last)
  - validate that `environment.production` was `true` (it is)
  - generate an other empty app from scratch doing the same process (in that case SW works...)

**Can i check something else? Did I forget something?**

If not my two last solutions are:

- moving module by module in the empty app to solved the problem without understanding the error
- lighting fire + shamanic songs...

Comment: There are some possible solutions in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8779

Comment: I didn't found clean solution for my problem as the link provided by @kikar said, it might be one of my dependencies.
The work around though solved the problem for me, I had to :
`if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the problem is caused by `angularFire2`. I had the same issue but was able to fix it by putting the following code in my `main.ts` file.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
}
```

Comment: I don't use angularFire2, but indeed it's related to some of my dependencies. I had to use the same workaround.

Comment: I had this issue. I'm using angularfire2 and this answer is correct.

Comment: I'm not using angularFire2 either, but this solved my problem as well.

Comment: Man, thank you so much.  I do use angularFire2 and this did work.  I had to put it below `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));` for it to work.  Not sure I would have ever figure this one out...  You are a major time saver!

Comment: Well, I'm not using angularFire2 but this made it work for me... kinda, still have some errors.

Answer (score 1):

a also had to change my base url to index.html, otherwise the service worker can not work by design:

index.html:

```
<base href="index.html">
```